# How to compile template with directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, interpolation

I need carousel with some html.

Workflow:

1. Get data from remote server
2. Insert HTML with remote data into carousel
3. Images should be scaled depending on dimensions( this is directive )

controller.js

```
var = '<div scale-image>{{data}}</div>'// I have html template file, but this is example
var interpolator = $interpolate(template);
interpolator({data: data});
```

**{{data}}** is inserted, but directive is not initialized( no log in console )

directive.js

```
function scaleImage() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(element);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can compile template by injecting $compile in the directive. 
the compiled template can be replaced with element or you can append within that element.
Here is directive.js, in which element is replaced by compiled template.

```
 function scaleImage($compile) {
      var template = '<div>{{data}}</div>';
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
        data: data
        },
      link: function(scope,element,attr) {
                 var content = $compile(template)(scope);
                 element.replaceWith(content);
            }
      }
    }
```

and in your html, you can use this directive as,

```
<div scale-image data="data"></div>
```

and in your controller,

```
  $scope.data =  //response from server
```

Comment: Maybe could use `scope:{data:'@'}`. Also, you could put 'template' as one of the properties returned like `return { restrict:'AE', template:'<div>{{data}}</div>'...}` so that it will be compiled automatically and you do not need to compile it by yourself in link function.